# How to make email link expire after X minutes in php?

Tags: php, date

I am working on email link expire after some **X** minutes where **X** denotes some **random date_time**. so my motive is to expire the the link after some time what ever I set the date_time in side the **$expire_date**.

So I just created dummy code myself just in order to sure my code works or not.

```
$currentDateTime = new \DateTime(); 
$currentDateTime-> setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('Asia/kolkata'));
$now = $currentDateTime-> format(' h:iA j-M-Y ');
$expire_date = "02:59PM 26-Mar-2019"; 

if($now > $expire_date) 
{ 
    echo " link is expired"; 
}
else{ 
    echo " link still alive "; 
}
```

I guess I am missing something in the above code, somehow the above code isn't working if anyone would point out the right direction or some better implementation it would be great.

Comment: Normally, you'd have stuff in the DB. e.g. a table with a unique token used in the URL, and against that row, an expiry datetime that you test against "now".

Comment: Your chosen date format starts with the time, that is not a format that can be meaningfully compared using string comparison. Why are you using string representations of the dates for the comparison in the first place?

Comment: yes I know about token and all other stuff just right now my motive is to make code simple to understand sir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing the times as strings. This does not work, as your first formatted string has a leading space.

Instead, try either removing the whitespace, or better, compare the times as DateTime objects:

```
$timezone = new \DateTimeZone('Asia/kolkata');

// Create the current DateTime object
$currentDateTime = new \DateTime(); 
$currentDateTime-> setTimezone($timezone);

// Create the given DateTime object
$expire_date = "02:59PM 26-Mar-2019"; 
$expireDateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat($expire_date, 'h:iA j-M-Y');

// Compare the objects
if($currentDateTime > $expireDateTime) 
{ 
    echo " link is expired"; 
}
else{ 
    echo " link still alive "; 
}
```

Comment: I try to change the $expire_date  more than current time but its still shows link is expired.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to compare dates in PHP, your best bet is to use *UNIX time stamps*. A UNIX time stamp is the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch (00:00:00 Thursday, 1 January 1970).

`time()` will return the current UNIX time stamp.
`strtotime()` will convert a date string into a UNIX time stamp.

So replacing these two lines:

```
$now = $currentDateTime-> format(' h:iA j-M-Y ');
$expire_date = "02:59PM 26-Mar-2019";
```

With these:

```
$now = time();
$expire_date = strtotime("02:59PM 26-Mar-2019");
```

Should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing date strings which will not work. You have to parse the string to a datetime object or timestamp before you can compare these values.

For example, using timestamps:

```
$expire_date = "02:59PM 26-Mar-2019"; 

if (time() > strtotime($expire_date)) { 
    echo "link is expired"; 
} else { 
    echo "link still alive "; 
}
```

Comment: They aren’t comparing DateTime to string, both $now and $expire_date where formatted date strings in the given example code.

Comment: thanks for your answer guyz but did you test your code? bcz if statement is not working. no matter whatever i change the time in $expire_date its says link still alive

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is use `strtotime` function and add inside `date` function and here you can specify `day, hour, minutes, seconds` as a perimeter. This way you can set time manually by adding +5 minutes or so on..

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata"); // set time_zone according to your location
$created = "2020-08-14 17:52"; // time when link is created 
$expire_date = date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime('+1 minutes',strtotime($created)));
//+1 day = adds 1 day
//+1 hour = adds 1 hour
//+10 minutes = adds 10 minutes
//+10 seconds = adds 10 seconds
//To sub-tract time its the same except a - is used instead of a +

$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); //current time


if ($now>$expire_date) { //if current time is greater then created time

    echo " Your link is expired";
}
else  //still has a time
{
   echo " link is still alive";
}
```