# PHP Create temporary link to page/file

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a website project, where you can login.

I want to make a system where you can request a file, but the link to the file should only be valid for a certain amount of time. After the certain amount of time the link should expire and stop working (maybe a show a 404 error).

-I am using php and MySQL database

Thank you!
*BTW: I am new on this platform*

Comment: I think this will solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55354454/how-to-make-email-link-expire-after-x-minutes-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with these 2 tables.
Whenever you upload file or manually add it, add an entry in the **files** table.
Whenever someone request a file, generate a link for it in **links** table like `https://host/download.php?id=the_random_string` which will point to the real file_id, with an expiry date.

### files

- id
- name
- physical_path

### links

- id
- file_id
- random_string
- expiry

So now you should have a file `download.php` (pseudo code)

```
$str = $_REQUEST['id'];
$sql = "select file_id from links where random_string=$str AND expiry hasn't passed";
$file_id = $row->file_id;
$sql = "select physical_path from files where id = $file_id";
$physical_path = $row->physical_path;
do_download($physical_path);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that using two ways...

### First Way

You can add timestamps on the URL where this URL is valid for a specific time (**You must take care of changing this timestamp by the user**) so, I recommend adding the timestamp as an arbitrary/inapprehensible string where the user can not change.

### Second Way

You can add the timestamp in the database with each file and before accessing the file you must check the stored timestamp if was exceed the current timestamp or not.